# Switch facingMode in opentok during a session

Tags: opentok, tokbox

Is it possible to switch the facingmode of your camera in the middle of an opentok session? I can set the facing mode when the session starts with publisherOptions but if I need to switch the facingmode of the camera during the session the only way I can see you can do it is to disconnect the session and start a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer. You just use

```
publisher.cycleVideo();
```

and cycles between front and back cameras.